# How to use the Google Script editor with Forms to collect respondent email and insert it into a sheet as an answer?

Tags: javascript, forms

Google Forms script to getRespondentEmail() into the connected spreadsheet along with all the answers. What I need is to create a form which uses something like collect email address option in the settings, **but** it can't be so that they can fill out whatever they want. I need their true address that they are logged into. It is to identify that they truly are the person they claim to be.

I am using a business G Suite acc, this is a project for our entire company so we should be not restricted from using this function the way we need it.

Thank you all for your useful answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the official settings on google. They allow for this. Now we can only use auto-input from our GSuite company e-mails and other people can't use the forms, but that is survivable.